# Vertica python client export to s3 parquet

Tags: python-3.x, vertica

I am trying to export data from Vertica to s3 parquet with Vetica python client. The command works great from vsql and all other commands work fine for me through python client. This one specific below doesn't want to work, gives exceptions.

```
query = "EXPORT TO PARQUET(directory = 's3://medibeedb/unified/" + table_name + "/" + site_name + \
                        "', fileSizeMB=1024)  AS SELECT '" + site_name + "' as site_name, *" \
                                                                         " from medibee." + r[0] + ";"  #+ i[0] + \

cur_unified.execute(query)
```

I prefer not to use s3export Vertica.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the exception message you get? And can you show us the original SQL you tried with VSQL - as the syntax of the query initialisation is not clear to me - especially ending in a  backslash ...